# Example of Polynomial time algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

What is the example of  polynomial time algorithm
Is polynomial time algorithm fastest?
Suppose 100 elements in array , then how can I decide algorithm is polynomial time?

Comment: @Miljen Mikic, what should be the value of k , is there any condition for k, not greater than size of array or any?

Comment: The exponent `k` should be at least > 0, but in some classifications even >= 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q:** What is the example of polynomial time algorithm?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d", i);
```

This is a linear algorithm, and linear belongs to polynomial class.

> **Q:** Is polynomial time algorithm fastest?

No, logarithmic and constant-time algorithms are asymptotically faster than polynomial algorithms.

> **Q:** Suppose 100 elements in array , then how can I decide algorithm is
>   polynomial time?

You haven't specified any algorithm here, just the data structure (array with 100 elements). However, to determine whether algorithm is polynomial time or not, you should find big-o for that algorithm. If it is `O(n^k)`, then it is polynomial time. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730717/while-calculating-bigoh-where-from-upper-bound-gn-comes/).

Comment: Please note that there are constant polynomials too (mathematically).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful You are right, but when speaking about classes of time complexities, usually the exponent should be >= 1 in order that algorithm belongs to the polynomial-time class. Quoting from Wikipedia: "algorithm with time complexity O(n^α) for some constant α ≥ 1 is a polynomial time algorithm."